# ¿Cómo agregar el constructor visual "Elementor" a mi plantilla de WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Construyendo mi theme desde un sitio que tenía en php, quiero replicar las páginas, pero al parecer no puedo instalar pluggins, o si los instalo, no funcionan. Cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con Xampp, con PHP version 5.2.0 (porque la ultima version me causa problemas).

Al instalar el Elementor Page Builder, e intentar usar el constructor, me dice que "es imposible cargar la vista previa" por lo que no funciona, además, instalé el plugin Nivo Slider y no puedo agregarlo a las páginas.

Tal vez no he agregado la función, pero por más que he buscado, no encuentro respuestas, soy novata en PHP.

functions.php:

```
<?php
 // Add scripts and stylesheets
  function chontalpalab_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.6', true );
}

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chontalpalab_scripts' );

 // WordPress Titles
  add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

 //Custom Logo
 add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );

 function themename_custom_logo_setup() {
   $defaults = array(
    'height'      => 116,
    'width'       => 350,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'flex-width'  => true,
    'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
 }
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themename_custom_logo_setup' );

 //Menu
 function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
  array(
   'topbar-menu' => __( 'Top Bar (optional)'),
   'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
   'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' ),
   'mobile-menu' => __( 'Mobile (optional)')
  )
 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );


/**
* Hide WordPress update nag to all but admins
*/

 function hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin() {
   if ( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
  }
 }
  add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin', 1 );

  /**
 * Insert custom login logo
 */

function custom_login_logo() {
   echo '
      <style>
          .login h1 a { 
            background-image: url(logo) !important; 
            background-size: 234px 67px; 
            width:234px; 
            height:67px; 
            display:block; 
        }
    </style>
';
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'custom_login_logo' );

// Support Featured Images
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: ¿Has usado los action hooks wp_head() y wp_footer() en tu theme?

Comment: No, apenas me estoy dando cuenta que necesitaba los hooks...